# A weird error when trying to write to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, cloudera-cdh

we have found an extrange and ocasional error when we try to write to the HDFS.
This is the exception:

```
http://pastebin.com/3YDX4a39
```

This is how the code looks:

```
http://pastebin.com/h1RW07qv
```

The exception happens when i am trying to instantiate the first time the fs field variable, line 12, when i try to invoke the method MyWatchService.saveInputDataIntoHDFS, the first thing to do is to instantiate the static part of MyHadoopUtils class,

```
fs = FileSystem.get(myConf);
```

this provokes the exception, but then in the exception i can see this message:

```
[INFO][FeedAdapter][2015-04-08 09:31:21] MyHadoopUtils:29 - HDFS instantiated! name: hdfs://dub-vcd-vms170.global.tektronix.net:8020
[INFO][FeedAdapter][2015-04-08 09:31:21] MyHadoopUtils:43 - HDFS fs instantiated? true
```

How can i remove that IOException?

I am running this in a linux enviroment,

```
    2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.centos.plus.x86_64, java version "1.7.0_71"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.3.2.el6_6-x86_64 u71-b14)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

    <hadoop-hdfs.version>2.5.0-cdh5.2.0</hadoop-hdfs.version>
    <hadoop-common.version>2.5.0-cdh5.2.0</hadoop-common.version>

    <!-- necessary to write within HDFS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-hdfs.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop-common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I response to myself, the problem is gone when i set up HADOOP_HOME variable

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs
```